# Eloquent: check extra pivot column

Tags: eloquent, pivot

Inside my User model I would like to make a isMember function.

```
public function isMember()
{
    return(\Auth::check() && "get the status value here" == 1)
}
```

I got two models. User, Club.

Their pivot table: club_user

```
user_id
club_id
status
```

The 'status' column holds 0 or 1. 
Now, how do i check the value for the extra column 'status'?

Update: 
It's a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public function isMember(){
if(\Auth::check())
  return (bool) $this->status;

return false;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the answer. That is a if statement without brackets. And i tried it out and it only returns false.

Comment: @Lynx-cro: this function returns a boolean value if the customer is a member or not.
I thought this is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work. If somebody got some suggestions how to make it better, please fell free.

```
public function isMember($clubId)
{
    $user = Club::find($clubId)->user()->where('club_user.user_id', \Auth::id())->first();
    if (is_object($user))
    {
        $status = $user->pivot->status;
     else
    {
    $status = 0;
    }
return (\Auth::user() && $status == 1);

}
```